# Using linq to delete and insert records from and to a dataset?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm working on a VB project for school.  It's a snake game, and I'm storing the high scores in a database.  I need to know how to insert and delete records from the dataset so that I can get rid of the old low score and insert a new high score.  We only covered LINQ very briefly in my class so I'm pretty clueless.

This is what I have so far and it all works.

```
Private Sub HighScores_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
   Handles MyBase.Load

    'See if player score is higher than the low score, and if so, add player name and score to database

    Me.HighscoresTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VbprojectDataSet.highscores)

    Dim lowScore = Aggregate scores In VbprojectDataSet.highscores
                   Select scores.score
                   Into Min()

    If GridForm.player.score > lowScore Then

        Dim lowScoreRow = From scores In VbprojectDataSet.highscores
                          Where scores.score = lowScore
                          Select scores

        GridForm.player.name = InputBox("You got a new high score! What is your name?", "SnakE")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why use LINQ for such DB operations? Is it one of the nessessery conditions? Plain vanilla ADO.NET would be much simpler in this case.

Comment: Is using a dataset a requirement? If so I think it is better to use the dataset itself to change and save data. If not, you may consider using [linq-to-sql](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1787244). It is really not hard to learn, but of course it's linq-based, so maybe a bridge to far for now.

Comment: This is a foundational class covering a lot of different topics. We just barely touched on using databases in our applications. The only requirement is that we have a database tied into our applications. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Entity Framework` you can keep the `LINQ` style and when you make changes to the entity objects all you have to do is call `.Save` on the `Enitity Container`.

[Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B#)